# Proper way to convert HTML to PDF

Tags: html, pdf, converters

I want to convert HTML page to PDF. There are several options, but they have some problems.

- Print HTML page in IE through `PDFCreator` (too cumbersome)
- Use `wkhtmltopdf` (low quality)
- Use `PhantomJS` (low quality)

Maybe I can use a complex solution? To print with `PhantomJS` through `PDFCreator`, or improve quality of `wkhtmltopdf`, or maybe something else?

Comment: can you tell the version of wkhtmltopdf you are using?

Comment: did you try 0.9 version(last stable)? cuz i don't have any quality issues.

Comment: Have a look at [pdfcrowd](http://pdfcrowd.com/hub/2011/04/18/convert-html-to-pdf-in-php.html)

Comment: I've just tried 0.9. It works slower and result is the same. I can't say that the quality is very poor, but compared to the `PDFCreator` it looks pretty bad :(  About `pdfcrowd` - I'm looking for some command-line tool, or something I can use with `c#`.

Comment: [cloudlayer.io](https://cloudlayer.io) actually uses headless Chrome instances to do the conversions so the quality will be exactly what you expect.  Might be worth looking into...

Comment: @ChruS Someone a while back asked me to make an HTML to PDF to print, this might be of use to you. You would just need to then download it, instead of displaying the print notification. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55294594/datatable-print-complex-header-print-preview/55426062#55426062

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you can try with [Amyuni WebkitPDF](http://www.amyuni.com/en/server/webkitpdf). It's not open source, but it's free for commercial use, and it can be used from C#.

Sample code for C# from the documentation:

```
static private void SaveToFile(string url, string file)
{        
    // Store the WebkitPDFContext returned value in an IntPtr
    IntPtr context = IntPtr.Zero;
    // Open the URL. The WebkitPDFContext returned value will be stored in
    // the passed in IntPtr
    int ret = WKPDFOpenURL(url, out context, 0, false);
    if (ret == 0)
    {
        // if ret is 0, then we succeeded in opening the URL.
        // Save the result as PDF to a file. Use the obtained context value
        ret = WKPDFSaveToFile(file, context);
    }
    if (ret != 0)
        Debug.WriteLine("Failed to run SaveToFile on '" + url + "' to generate file '" + file + "'");
    // Make sure to close the WebkitPDFContext because otherwise the
    // internal PDFCreator as well as other objects will not be released
    WKPDFCloseContext(context);
}
```

*Usual disclaimer applies*.

Answer (score 2):

You can properly convert HTML to PDF using GroupDocs.Conversion for .NET [API](https://products.groupdocs.com/conversion/net). 
Have a look at the code:

```
// Setup Conversion configuration and Initailize ConversionHandler    
ConversionConfig config = new ConversionConfig();    
config.StoragePath = "source file storage path";    
// Initailize ConversionHandler    
ConversionHandler conversionHandler = new ConversionHandler(config);    
// Convert and save converted document    
var convertedDocumentPath = conversionHandler.Convert("sample.html", new PdfSaveOptions{});    
convertedDocumentPath.Save("result-" + Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension("sample.html") + ".pdf");
```

*Disclosure: I work as Developer Evangelist at GroupDocs.*

Answer (score 2):

patched wkhtmltopdf (a very good WebKit-based command line tool, fast) with `--print-media-type --no-stop-slow-scripts` keys

`chromium --headless --no-zygote --single-process ... --print-to-pdf= ...` (slower, Portrait orientation only)

chromium headless via DevTools Protocol (slow, only a few programming languages do have bindings to)

wrapper around Blink Engine (e.g., Qt5 https://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qtwebengine.git/tree/examples/webenginewidgets/html2pdf?h=5.15)

If you believe in containers, - https://github.com/thecodingmachine/gotenberg (internally - chromium headless via DevTools Protocol)

Answer (score 1):

google chrome `Save as PDF`
the output looks exactly the same (as rendered by chrome)

here, I use Puppeteer to automate the process: singlefile or in Folder
https://github.com/FuPeiJiang/puppeteer-pdf

Answer (score -1):

```js
// npm i jspdf
// npm i html2canvas

SavePDF(fileName: any) {
  let section = (document.querySelector('#mainContainer') as HTMLElement);
  html2canvas(section, {
    scale: 2, // Canvas Quality
  }).then((canvas: any) => {
    var link = document.createElement('a');
    link.href = canvas.toDataURL();
    link.download = fileName;
    document.body.appendChild(link);
    // link.click(); // To Download Image
    // open()?.document.write('<img src="'+canvas.toDataURL()+'"/>');
    var pdf = new jsPDF("p", "pt", "a4", true); // true and false for compress
    const imgProps = pdf.getImageProperties(canvas.toDataURL());
    const pdfWidth = pdf.internal.pageSize.getWidth();
    const pdfHeight = (imgProps.height * pdfWidth) / imgProps.width;
    pdf.addImage(canvas.toDataURL(), 'PNG', 0, 0, pdfWidth, pdfHeight, 'FAST'); // NONE, FAST, MEDIUM and SLOW,
    window.open(URL.createObjectURL(pdf.output("blob")))
    pdf.save('file_name' + '.pdf');
  });
}
```

```html
<div id="mainContainer">
  <p>Hello World</p>
</div>
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).