# Print page in PhantomJS

Tags: javascript, pdf, printing, phantomjs

Is there any way to print a page in `PhantomJS`. I want to pass my page to PDF Printer (`PDFCreator`) in order to get a good-looking PDF page (*See my question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12837560/proper-way-to-convert-html-to-pdf)*)

I'm using the following code, but it doesn't work

```
var page = require('webpage').create(),
address, output, size;

var input = phantom.args[0];
page.open(input, function (status) {
    page.evaluate(function () {
        window.print();
    });
    phantom.exit();
});
```

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't work"? Are any errors thrown? I'm thinking that trying to print from a headless browser will never work, as browsers typically throw up the system print dialog, and PhantomJS won't see it...

Comment: There are no errors, just nothing happens. Maybe you are right about system print dialog... What can I do in this situation?

Comment: See my answer. I don't know about the quality, but it looks like it has the capability...

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this helps: You need to set a larget timeout in `rasterize.js` in order to allow for the entire document to render before you do `page.render(output)`

Also, the script you provided is very different from what `rasterize.js`does and it won't work.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like [PhantomJS has examples included on its website](http://phantomjs.org/examples/). One of them, [rasterize.js](https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/blob/master/examples/rasterize.js), says it shows how to output the HTML as a PDF. I haven't tried it, but perhaps that could lead to a solution.

Comment: I've used `rasterize.js` but it produces empty document. My page is pretty big (PDFCreator produces 60 pages), this is the problem I think.

Comment: You may want to amend your question to include what you've tried, what didn't work, etc. Otherwise, people waste time posting answers which you've already tried...

Answer (score 0):

I found this gist: https://gist.github.com/boriscy/a0ac26c54f30296949df which does what looks like a crucial thing:

```js
page.onLoadFinished = function() {
  page.render(pdf);
  phantom.exit();
}
```

The other examples I have seen put in a big wait and just hope by the time the wait is over the document is done. To me that doesn't seem great as bigger documents will fail, and smaller documents will be slower than needed.