# datatable print complex header print preview

Tags: javascript, html, datatable

hi im working with datatable and its great but i have problem thats in complex header like this

```
<thead>
    <tr><td>some text</td></tr>
    <tr><td>some text</td></tr>
</thead>
```

now in showing page its like like this 
[image]
when i hit print preview i gat result like this 
[image]

that the first `tr` in `thead` is gone 
i opened datatable.js file and i found this

```
        var addRow = function ( d, tag ) {
        var str = '<tr>';

        for ( var i=0, ien=d.length ; i<ien ; i++ ) {
            // null and undefined aren't useful in the print output
            var dataOut = d[i] === null || d[i] === undefined ?
                '' :
                d[i];
            var classAttr = columnClasses[i] ?
                'class="'+columnClasses[i]+'"' :
                '';

            str += '<'+tag+' '+classAttr+'>'+dataOut+'</'+tag+'>';
        }

        return str + '</tr>';
    };

    // Construct a table for printing
    var html = '<table class="'+dt.table().node().className+'">';

    html += '<thead>';

    // Adding logo to the page (repeats for every page while print)
    if(config.repeatingHead.logo) {
        var logoPosition = (['left','right','center'].indexOf(config.repeatingHead.logoPosition) > 0) ? config.repeatingHead.logoPosition : 'right';
        html += '<tr><th colspan="'+data.header.length+'" style="padding: 0;margin: 0;text-align: '+logoPosition+';"><img style="'+config.repeatingHead.logoStyle+'" src="'+config.repeatingHead.logo+'"/></th></tr>';
    }

    // Adding title (repeats for every page while print)
    if(config.repeatingHead.title) {
        html += '<tr><th colspan="'+data.header.length+'">'+config.repeatingHead.title+'</th></tr>';
    }

    if ( config.header ) {
        html += addRow( data.header, 'th' );
    }

    html += '</thead>';

    html += '<tbody>';
    for ( var i=0, ien=data.body.length ; i<ien ; i++ ) {
        html += addRow( data.body[i], 'td' );
    }
    html += '</tbody>';

    if ( config.footer && data.footer ) {
        html += '<tfoot>'+ addRow( data.footer, 'th' ) +'</tfoot>';
    }
    html += '</table>';
```

and its just add the last tr in thead 
but i couldn't put the first tr with print preview 
thanks a lot

this is a jsfiddle ex
when you preview the table its showing with tow row at thead
but in print preview its showing only on tr in thead

[enter link description here](https://jsfiddle.net/ogkvu4xp/)

Comment: Can you please add problem and solution that can be understood?

Comment: Can you create a stack snippet/jsFiddle to verify it?

Comment: i upload example on jsfiddle

Comment: @AwarPulldozer  Do want exactly header and footer should be in print view right?

Comment: yes thats what i want

Comment: why not just use
    <thead>
        <tr><td>some text<br/>some text</td></tr>
    </thead>?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You asked for a work-around and since it is already mentioned not a feature for Datatables at the moment. You could simply convert it to a PDF through grabbing only the tables contents. Then add styling for the print window without any libraries. It really is just a window.

It is just a matter of injecting the right style before loading the window. So we just need to make sure we grab the style outputted by datatables and inject that.

[image]

> CSS

```
    table
    {
        width: 300px;
        font-size: 17px;
    }
    table, th, td
    {
        border: solid 1px #DDD;
        border-collapse: collapse;
        padding: 2px 3px;
        text-align: center;
    }        table
    {
        width: 300px;
        font-size: 17px;
    }
    table, th, td
    {
        border: solid 1px #DDD;
        border-collapse: collapse;
        padding: 2px 3px;
        text-align: center;
    }
```

> HTML

```
<div id="print-window">
    <table id="example" class="display" style="width:100%">
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th rowspan="2">Name</th>
            <th colspan="2">HR Information</th>
            <th colspan="3">Contact</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>Position</th>
            <th>Salary</th>
            <th>Office</th>
            <th>Extn.</th>
            <th>E-mail</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
            <td>System Architect</td>
            <td>$320,800</td>
            <td>Edinburgh</td>
            <td>5421</td>
            <td>t.nixon@datatables.net</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Garrett Winters</td>
            <td>Accountant</td>
            <td>$170,750</td>
            <td>Tokyo</td>
            <td>8422</td>
            <td>g.winters@datatables.net</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Ashton Cox</td>
            <td>Junior Technical Author</td>
            <td>$86,000</td>
            <td>San Francisco</td>
            <td>1562</td>
            <td>a.cox@datatables.net</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Cedric Kelly</td>
            <td>Senior Javascript Developer</td>
            <td>$433,060</td>
            <td>Edinburgh</td>
            <td>6224</td>
            <td>c.kelly@datatables.net</td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
        <tfoot>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Position</th>
            <th>Salary</th>
            <th>Office</th>
            <th>Extn.</th>
            <th>E-mail</th>
        </tr>
        </tfoot>
    </table>
</div>
<input type="button" value="Print" onclick="pdf()" />
```

> Javascript

```
function pdf() {
    let t = document.getElementById('print-window').innerHTML;

    let style = "<style>";
    style = style + "table {width: 100%; font-size: 17px;}";
    style = style + "table, th, td {border: solid 1px #DDD; border-collapse: collapse;";
    style = style + "padding: 2px 3px;text-align: center;}";
    style = style + "</style>";
    let win = window.open('', '', 'height=700,width=700');

    win.document.write('<html><head>');
    win.document.write('<title>Profile</title>');
    win.document.write(style);
    win.document.write('</head>');
    win.document.write('<body>');
    win.document.write(t);
    win.document.write('</body></html>');

    win.document.close();
    win.print();
}
```

Comment: thanks man after all i changed to https://bootstrap-table.com bc when your report is 50 page and more making pdf and put data inside tack much time i guess bootstrap-table is much easer to use but i guess a lot of people search about this solution

Answer (score 3):

As discussed in [this](https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/36666/print-two-headers) topic from [Datatables website](https://datatables.net), this feature is not yet available.

Comment: i know that but i ask if anyone can fix it here